# JQuery animation not sliding/broken

Tags: jquery-animate, sliding

First, im not really experienced with javascript or jquery, usually the plugins or very very simple code by hand (as you are about to see).

Wat i want is done many times, but for some reason i cannot get it to work like i would.
I have several problems.

I use the .animation to slide 2 divs in and out (2 divs next to each other, and i want them to slide in and out of the screen (like the iphone homescreen for example).

Now the problem is the animation does not work as intended, instead of sliding away div1 WHILE sliding in div2 along side of div1, div1 disapears/shrinks (sliding up and left) instead of "sliding outside of the screen" and then div2 shows up afterwards. (so the slide effect is not working and the divs hide and show seperatly instead of sliding like a iphone screen).

Now the thing is i have recreated the setup and tried on there, and it works as intended as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkeulen/2fHbz/

So that is how i want it to work, but it does not do so as show here: (NOTE: its work in progress) http://jsfiddle.net/dkeulen/gQ9aE/2/
(Black square on the right center is the button you need to click).

I could post all the html and css and jquery here but its quite the amount to post...
If anything els is needed i can provide it ofcourse.

As code this is the part i use for the sliding:

```
$('.btnr').click(function(){
            $('#hosting').animate({'width' : '0px'}, 100).hide(600);
            $('#inexchange').animate({'width' : '100%'}, 600).show(600);
            $('.btnl').fadeIn(600);
            $('.btnr').fadeOut(600);
});

$('.btnl').click(function(){
            $('#hosting').animate({'width' : '100%'}, 600).show(400);
            $('#inexchange').animate({'width' : '0px'}, 600).hide(600);
            $('.btnl').fadeOut(600);
            $('.btnr').fadeIn(600);
});
```

I hope anyone can help me out on what goes wrong and what i must do about it, thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to specify a jsfiddle for us to see it in action
I think your problem is that the hide() and show() doesn't stack in the same animation queue

so one way of solving this is using `promise` ex.

```
$('.btnr').click(function(){
            promise1 = $('#hosting').animate({'width' : '0px'}, 100).promise();
            $.when(promise1).then(
                function(){
                   $('#hosting').hide();
                   $('#inexchange').animate({'width' : '100%'}, 600).show(600);
                   $('.btnl').fadeIn(600);
                   $('.btnr').fadeOut(600);
            });
});
```

the same goes for the other button.

check this simple fiddle I made to demonstrate how it's working
http://jsfiddle.net/artmees/BCTxH/

Comment: Hey Artmees, thanks for the quick response.
Unfortunatly this reproduces the same behaviore i have with my own code.

Comment: My guess is the problem is a combination of the jquery i made and the css, but after a few hours testing and breaking out code one by one i still cant find the problem...

Comment: could you provide a js fiddle to test with the css so i could might help ? and also please note that animate might take a callback function described [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that could do the same promise did...

Comment: Will add a jsfiddle of the main site tommorow when im back at work.

Comment: added jsfiddle of the problem page. link 2